# Sitting 100 people at 5 tables all possibilities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Edit: We have 100 people and 5 distinct tables (t1,t2,t3,t4,t5) from which they can sit. I'm trying to find the number of ways which they can be seated. Note that a table can be left empty so we can have 100 people on the first table.

I've been trying to answer this one out but I feel like I'm not going in the right direction.
I know about circular permutation so my first thought was for each table you have 99! ways of sitting them. So I thought well you can seat them 99! ways at first table or 99! ways at second, etc. so it would end up as 5*99! because there is 5 table. But that doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: I think by 5 tables you mean 5 seats, but why there is $99!$ choices to put in the first seat ? Give that another thought.

Comment: I think you have to consider cases where multiple tables are occupied. If there’s no distinction between the tables then what you wrote should just be $99!$.

Comment: I meant 5 tables. Each table can have any number of seats hence why I mentioned all possibilities.

Comment: There is distinction between tables, you can see it as t1 t2 t3 t4 t5.

Answer (score 1):

Now each person can sit on any table of the five,  so that is $5^{100}$ ways.

Comment: I updated hope it's clearer.

Comment: For some reason that doesn't make sense, why aren't you using the (n-1)! notation here?

Comment: It is not a must to include the factorial, the first person has 5 choices, and the second also has 5 choices after the first one chooses (that is $5×5$) and so on ...

Comment: We use factorial usually when repetition is not allowed. For example if you have $100$ chairs, and $100$ persons, you have $100$ choices to place a person on the first chair, now for the second chair, you have $99$ choices, because we already placed a person on the first chair, and so on ... $100×99×98×..=100!$ (Very similar to the idea of the uses $_nP_r$, it can be used here also). But in your question, if the first person chooses the first table, the second person can also choose the first table (so repetition is allowed).